# How to validate form(using javascript) and run a function if form is valid?

Tags: javascript, validation

`<form onsubmit="myfunction()">//sign up content</form>`

```
function myfunction() {
                document.getElementById('signUpContent').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('MessageToBeDisplayed').style.display = "block";
            }
```

I'm making a website sign up page and in that when i click the submit  button,i have set it to validate my form but I am unable to use both form validation and `onclick`.If the user's input is correct then it should perform the `onclick` function.

i have tried adding `onclick`and `onsubmit` events to both button and form tags but it doesnt work

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: Please be more clear in the formulation of your question and add a code example to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use onclick  or onsubmit but you have to use onclick on submit button and onsubmit on form, and then you can validate form and if something goes wrong, `return` something and code execution will be stopped

here is example

```
 $form.onsubmit = function(){
   if($input.value.length < 1){
      return false;
   }
   alert('Form validated successfully')
 }
```

**EDIT**

as you edited your post, i think you are not trying to send data to server, and form is usually used for that, in that case if you want to change designes of html elements you must prevent default form action (maybe you have noticed that when you click submit button page reloads and inputed data is added on search bar) you can do it with `e.preventDefault()` and by the way i can not properly understand what you need because there is not validation in your code. why do you need to use both form validation and onclick.

here is example of what i understand of the action you need (based on your code)

```
 document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     document.getElementById('signUpContent').style.display="none";
     document.getElementById('MessageToBeDisplayed').style.display="block";         
     //do your validation
 }
```

and if you need action based on button click you can do it

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('signUpContent').style.display = "none"         
    document.getElementById('MessageToBeDisplayed').style.display = "block";
    //do your validation
}
```

and if this does not help please provide more information what you need your describtion is way too obscure.

Comment: Thanks but that wasn't the answer i expected. I guess i hadn't made it clear. Sorry. Pls check the question again,I have posted a code...

Comment: mark my answer as correct if it answers your question

Comment: Thanks a lot...about validation i used client side validation html/js validation..so what i need is- If the users information is valid then when the user clicks submit this message should be displayed...and i am going to send the data to server..it's a work in progress..thanks..and if you any more suggestions,please help

Comment: then you gotta first validate inputs and as I said if it goes wrong `return` something and code will stop executing.

Comment: ok thanks and please check my other question as well

Comment: which other question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56580802/can-i-use-onclick-and-onsubmit-events-together

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just change  to a button and onclick function on it.

When onclick function will be called, add one if condition in it to validate form, so you can check if form is valid, if valid then go forward, else go back to form and update what is wrong.

```
if(checkIsFormValid()){
// do whatever you want to do on onclick
}
```